# Creating a scrollable list inside a HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript code that dynamically appends rows to the HTML table, and every cell in a row should contain a single unordered list. So normally, I need to also create a list in Javascript, and assign it to the cell parent. I did that, but from some reason my list is not scrollable, and the cell is not the size that in the CSS I assigned it to be. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate if someone could point out the mistake. Here is the code.

So what I need is a **scrollable** list inside a HTML table cell.

down vote
unaccept
You can delete the rows after getting the data from the server

```
$.getJSON("/data/"+data, function(dataState) {

   $("#data_table tr").remove();
       //...

        for(var data in dataState) {


                var row = document.createElement("tr");

               var list = document.createElement("ul");

                            for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                                // Create the list item:
                                var item = document.createElement('li');

                                var dataName = data[j].name;

                                // Set its contents:
                                item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataName));

                                // Add it to the list:
                                list.appendChild(item);
                            }

                           // make a list scrollable and add to cell
                            cell.appendChild(list);
                            cell.className = "cellDiv";
                            list.className = "listScrollable";

                tableRef.appendChild(row);
            }

        }

    });
```

and the CSS:

```
.cellDiv {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 10%;

  font-family: Monaco;
  font-size: larger;

  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.listSrollable {
  width:20%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow: hidden;

  font-family: Monaco;

  background-color: white;
}
```

The whole code is to big to copy it all, but the critical part is here. So I am guessing that the problem is conflicting styling for the cell and scrollable list, but not sure how to fix.

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

The overflow: hidden overwrites the overflow-y. If you use auto instead of scroll. The scrollbar is only visible, when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: scroll` (or `auto`) on `<td>` and assign `min-height/width` according to this pattern:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
tr {
  min-height: 100px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
ol {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**Note:** The default behavior of a table is to conform to the height of it's content, and scrolling is used in an situation when the content exceeds the borders or visible limits of the container. So when you want control of a `<td>`'s height, place a block element within it and control the block element instead.

#### SNIPPET

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
tr {
  min-height: 100px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
ol {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
          <li>CONTENT</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>&nbsp;</ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```